# How to get the previously sent message from messenger chatbot

Tags: php, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

How can I get the previous message in messenger chatbot? So that my bot can understand what the user is saying and reply on it.
As an example,

(News bot)
USER : Show me news about donald trump
BOT : Here's 3 sir!.... Would you like more?
USER: Yes.

So, when user says **yes** the bot has to know that he wants news from **donald trump**. So, I need that bot remember about **donald trump**.

How to get the previous message or how to remember the **donald trump** phrase?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest looking back to the previous message because this can lead to unexpected results. For example, what if the user unexpectedly sends two messages - how would the bot know what message to look for?

Instead, treat the conversation as a series of states that you cache server side. Using this example, when the user sends 'Show me news about donald trump' you should cache something like '{last_query: 'donald trump'} on your server. Then when the user asks for more articles, you can retrieve the query from the most recent conversation state.

Comment: If you DO want to get the previous message, you can use the /{conversation-id}/messages endpoint of the graph api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/conversation/messages